# C++ with sqlite: "library routine called out of sequence

Tags: c++, sqlite

If I run the following code (only the relevant part is shown), I'll get the error message: "library routine called out of sequence".

```
// Open database
char *lang = "Spanish";
char *DBName = "Spanish.db";
sqlite3 *db;
int sqlret;

sqlret = sqlite3_open(DBName, &db);

if (sqlret != SQLITE_OK) {
    printf("Can't open database: %s \n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 1;
}

// Create Table

sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
char *sqlcommand;
sqlcommand = new char;

Start(sqlcommand, lang);

printf(sqlcommand);

sqlret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlcommand, -1, &stmt, NULL);

if (sqlret != SQLITE_OK) {
    printf("Error: %s \n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 2;
}
```

Start(a,b) is the following function:

```
void Start(char *command, char *language) {

sprintf(command,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'Vocabulary' ( "\
                "'%s' TEXT NOT NULL, ", language);
strcat(command, "'Native Language' TEXT NOT NULL, " \
                "'Times Asked' INT NOT NULL, " \
                "'Times Correct' INT NOT NULL, " \
                "'Times Wrong' INT NOT NULL );");
}
```

However, if I don't define sqlcommand dynamically but static (What I mean is: char *sqlcommand= "CREATE ...";), it works. I would appreciate it if you helped me!

Comment: Just to nitpick: There isn't any C++ code in there, just C.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Wrong, there is a `new` (which even seems to be the culprit) :)

Answer (score 1):

`sqlcommand = new char;`

This allocates memory for **one single** character. Which, by the way, you never delete.

You don't want a single character but a whole string. Technically, this means you'd need a pair of `new[]` and `delete[]` calls. However, in C++ you don't use raw strings if you don't have to. You certainly don't have to use them here.

**Use `std::string` instead!**

This also allows you to get rid of the low-level `sprintf` and `strcat` functions. Here is the result:

```
std::string Start(std::string const &language)
{
    return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'Vocabulary' ( "\
        "'" + language + "' TEXT NOT NULL, "
        "'Native Language' TEXT NOT NULL, "
        "'Times Asked' INT NOT NULL, "
        "'Times Correct' INT NOT NULL, "
        "'Times Wrong' INT NOT NULL );"
}
```

For compatibility with C functions such as the ones from the SQLite API, `std::string` offers the `c_str()` member function:

```
std::string sqlcommand = Start(lang);
sqlret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlcommand.c_str(), -1, &stmt, NULL);
```

In short, you really need to learn using strings in C++. Your life will become considerably easier :)

---

**Edit:** Just to mention this... The error message you experience apparently stems from undefined behaviour inside of SQLite, because you passed it an invalid `char` pointer (one that is not null-terminated -- another C thing you can forget in C++).

Comment: Given that the process apparently did not crash, the `char*` is getting NUL-terminated by (`sprintf` and `strcat`) - but it's trashing whatever is on the heap there.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: I think the most precise thing one could say here is that the sprintf call already yields UB.